# mysqli_prepare statment rows not updating

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The below function is executing the `$stmt` and printing success, but it is showing zero rows have been updated. If i run the sql manually it will update the database. But its not being updated from the php code below. Am i missing something ?

```
 function updateLastActive($link, $id) {

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"update `account` set `lastActive` =now() where  id = ?"); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows; 
        echo 'success';
        echo $num_of_rows;
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }}
```

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: Is `$id` valid in your code?

Comment: try $stmt->affected_rows or mysqli_affected_rows($stmt)

Comment: $stmt->affected_rows. This is printing show 1 row affected. The timestamp isnt correct though. It doesnt seem to update at all when i refresh in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**mysqli_affected_rows()**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE,
>   REPLACE or DELETE query.

Use `mysqli_affected_rows()` instead `$stmt->num_rows`

```
 if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        $num_of_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($link));
        echo 'success';
        echo $num_of_rows;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```